# Using Fread in C

Tags: c, encoding, base64, decode, fread

Hi I am new to C and am having trouble making a base 64 encoder. I have a file, *in, that is being passed in. I want to take 57, 8 bit characters at a time. Would I do something along the lines of 'freed(?,57,8,in)' Im not sure what the first ? is, I know it is a pointer but Im not sure to what. I think I want to store them in an array so maybe the ? is the array? Im sorry that I am so confused and if I worded this badly. Thank you very much. If possible could someone maybe give me an example of what the freed would look like.

Answer (score 0):

`fread(ptr, 1, 57, input_file);`

*where:*

1. `ptr` is a pointer to a memory area with anough space to hold 57
   characters (in this case).
2. `1` is the size in bytes `fread()` will read from the stream
   pointed by `input_file`.
3. `57` the amout of `1` byte elements you want to read.

Keep in mind that they are some rare platforms where 1 byte could have more than 8-bits, so keep this in mind if you are doing operations with a fixed amount of bits.

Also, I hope you are not implementing a Base64 encoder by yourself, use a library for this matter, they are plenty of them with a code base heavily tested.